# "Fetch as Google" doesn't find the HTML snapshot for my AJAX content

Tags: seo, google-search-console, crawlable-ajax, fetch-as-google, escaped-fragment

For my webpage I generate the content via JavaScript, so I want to use `?_escaped_fragment_` to redirect Google to my HTML snapshot.

I have a RewriteRule for my Apache

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshot/.snapshot_.html [NC,L]
```

Which redirects `?_escaped_fragment_=` to `/snapshot/.snapshot_.html` (`http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=`). This works fine.

I also added `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` to my homepage.

When I do "Fetch as Google" in my Webmaster Tools, it doesn't fetch the content of the ugly url but from example.com.

Is there anything I did not consider?

Comment: Does your website really only have a single snapshot?   Most AJAX websites would have many snapshots.

Comment: yep, its just one page without any internal links

Comment: So why are you using AJAX at all?  If you just have one piece of content, shouldn't you just have a static page?

Comment: I just said AJAX to point out that its async. Actually it's a template engine rendering my page. It basically comes down to the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Fetch as Google" does not fetch the same way as Google does. "Fetch as Google" doesn't check the page for the meta tag. (The crawling algorithm does)

A workaround is adding it manually in the "fetch as Google" statement. ex:

`www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=`

Comment: Do you have a reference for this, or is this based on personal experience?

Comment: This is based on personal experience. I did a quick search for a reference but couldn't find one. [Here is a  link that describes the same problem and the same solution](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/EixALB3VMC4)

Answer (score 1):

Google's John Mueller [answered a similar question in the Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/YaOZrKGYrGA):

> For URLs that use the AJAX-crawling scheme, you need to submit the "escaped-fragment" versions in Fetch as Google. The "hash-bang" URLs themselves won't work there.

It appears that "Fetch as Google" isn't able to handle hash bang URLs or fragment meta tags.